# Find in mongoDb ->Find behaves strange

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Doesn't work:

```
Locations.find({ query: { _id: apartment.location }}).then(result=>result[0]);
```

Works:

```
Locations.find({ Fake: { _id: apartment.location }}).then(result=>result[0]);
```

Works:

```
Locations.find({ '_id': apartment.location }).then(result => result[0]);
```

Don't get why this happens.

P.S. _id is "String" in db not an ObjectId.

Comment: Do the two working ones locate the same document?

Comment: Assuming this is Mongoose, only the last one is supported.

Comment: @John yes all are same

Comment: @JohnnyHK its the mongoClient. Strange that 2nd syntax runs. Even replace Fake with anything it runs but just not with "query".